# Extending a probability measure to a finer $\sigma$-algebra

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

This is probably a trivial question, but hopefully someone can help me with it:

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mu)$ be a probability space, i.e., $\mathcal{F}$ is a $\sigma$-field on $\Omega$ and $\mu$ is probability measure on $\mathcal{F}$ (in particular, $\mu$ is countably additive, and $\mu(\Omega)=1$). Let $\mathcal{F}'$ be a $\sigma$-field on $\Omega$ such that $\mathcal{F}' \supsetneq \mathcal{F}$.

What are the necessary and/or sufficient conditions under which the following is true:

There exists a probability measure $\mu'$ on $\mathcal{F}'$ such that for each $A \in \mathcal{F}$, $\mu'(A) = \mu(A)$.

I know that it is possible to construct such a probability measure $\mu'$ if $\mathcal{F}$ has atoms -- but does there exist such a $\mu'$ if the $\sigma$-algebras do not have atoms?

Thanks!

Comment: Think about $\mathcal F' = 2^\Omega$.

Comment: @cardinal: Thanks! Do you mean to say that any probability measure $\mu$ on some $\sigma$-algebra on $\Omega$ can be extended to some probability measure $\mu'$ on the power set? I suspected that, but I can't see the formal argument. And if the above is true, can we then obtain a probability measure $\mu''$ on any sub-$\sigma$ algebra $\mathcal{F}''$ of the power set by restricting $\mu'$ to $\mathcal{F}''$? Thanks for your help -- I know I must be missing something trivial.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/200677/7003

Comment: @cardinal - many thanks! I should have seen this right away. For the record/future readers: The answer is: This cannot be done in general. For example, the Lebesgue measure on (the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on) [0,1] cannot be extended to the power set.

Comment: Assuming the continuum hypothesis.

Comment: For future users -- for the specific problem I was working on, the following paper has precisely the results I needed:M.P. Ershov (Yershov), EXTENSION OF MEASURES AND STOCHASTIC EQUATIONS, THEORY OF PROBABILITY AND ITS APPLICATI0NS, Volume XIX (3), 1974.